# Unfamiliar with Notation for a Log

Tags: logarithms

Probably a stupid question, but I need to rank a selection of a few functions by growth rate, and there's a notation for one of the log functions I'm unfamiliar with. What I'm seeing is a log raised directly to an exponent - is this the same as how cos(x)*cos(x) is written as cos^2(x)? Attached is a screenshot. I've plugged log^3 into Desmos to try and visualize the function, but it doesn't even graph it, and I haven't found anything helpful on Google. Could anybody explain the notation to me?
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNNQj.jpg)

Comment: Short answer: yes. That distinguishes it from $\log (x^3)=3\log x$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Desmos gives you a warning, iirc, if you try to plot a function ^3 or higher. Desmos supports e.g. $\sin^2$ notation but not $\sin^3$ notation (this was true the last time I tried)